# How can I search for files based on elements of a list?

Tags: python, list, glob

I have a list `tile` with elements like these

```
G11451-11500
G11501-11550
G11551-11600
G11601-11650
```

Which I want to use to search a directory and store the files in a list.

For example, this : `glob.glob('*G11451-11500*.sh')`gives me the intended output with a list of filenames.

But I want to do this in a loop. And I am unable to proceed from here:

```
for ix in tile:
        e = glob.glob('*format(ix)*')
```

Comment: what is the exact out put you want to acheive from the list ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `str.format` and pass `ix` into the string:

```
e = glob.glob('*{}*.sh'.format(ix))
```

If you're reading these strings from some external source (such as a file), ensure you've removed the trailing newlines with `str.strip`.